# Date is not changing in the datepicker xamarin forms

Tags: xamarin.forms

Date is always set to date of today and not listening to the change

this is the view model

```
   public TaskReportViewModel()
    {
        from = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");

        to = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd");
    }

    public string _to;

    public string to
    {
        get { return _to; }
        set
        {
            _to = value;
            OnPropertyChange("to");
        }
    }
```

and this is the view

```
    <DatePicker x:Name="dateFrom" Date="{Binding from}" 
      HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" Margin="8" 
            DateSelected="dateFrom_DateSelected">
            <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
        </DatePicker>
```

this the page class

```
        this.BindingContext = new TaskReportViewModel();

        dateFrom.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        dateFrom.BindingContext = new TaskReportViewModel();

        dateTo.Format = "yyyy-MM-dd";
        dateTo.BindingContext = new TaskReportViewModel();
```

Comment: How does your `from` property look like?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason it is not working is that you are binding a string type to a DateTime type what you should be doing instead is something like this :

First, you need to add a property like this:

```
private DateTime _toDateTime = DateTime.Now;
public DateTime ToDateTime
    {
        get { return _toDateTime; }
        set { _toDateTime = value; OnPropertyChanged(nameof(ToDateTime)); }
    }
```

And then change the DatePicker as shown here:

```
     <DatePicker x:Name="dateFrom" Date="{Binding ToDateTime, Mode=TwoWay}" 
  HorizontalOptions="StartAndExpand" WidthRequest="300" Margin="8" 
        DateSelected="dateFrom_DateSelected">
                    <DatePicker.Format>yyyy-MM-dd</DatePicker.Format>
     </DatePicker>
```

Comment: still getting the same date of today :(

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve here, if you want to know which date formats are supporteded check this http://www.csharp-examples.net/string-format-datetime/

Comment: i want to set the default date for today but when select any other dates change to it at the view model

Comment: Oh like that okay wait let me change it a bit here

Comment: @Rana Done take a look

Comment: Thanks buddy it's working fine now but how to send the date in the format "yyyy-MM-dd"? can you help me please?

Comment: format it using to string and then reconvert it to datetime

Comment: how to do that please?